# Composition in Java - Getting a null output

Tags: java, composition

I am new to java and trying to use composition for the first time. I built this class called Person, who takes as an attribute a string name, and an object pAddress. It has two constructors and one copy constructor, a method to set the PAddress attribute and a method String toString:

```
public class Person {
private String name;
private Address pAddress;
    ///*constructor that gets the city, street, number, zip from    Address class*/
public Person (String name, String city, String street, int number, int zip)
{
    this.name=name;
    pAddress =new Address(city, street, number, zip);
}

public Person (String name, Address a)
{
    this.name=name;
    pAddress = new Address (a);
}
//**copy constructor**
public Person (Person other){
    this.name=other.name;
    this.pAddress= new Address (pAddress);}
//**set method for pAddress**
public void setPAddress(String city, String street, int number, int zip)
{
    pAddress.setCity(city);
    pAddress.setNumber(number);
    pAddress.setStreet(street);
    pAddress.setZip(zip);
}
**//String toString method**
public String toString(){
    return this.name  + ", " + pAddress;
```

}

However, when I try to print the String toString method, I get a NULL value for the object part. to be more specific:

```
public static void main (String[]args){

    Address Home=new Address("New York","5th Avenue", 112, 111);

    Person a=new Person("Carl",Home);

    System.out.println(a);
}
```

The last println comes out:

```
Carl, Address: nullst., 0, null
```

The Address class is listed below:

```
public class Address {
private String city, street;
private int number, zip;
public Address (String c, String s, int n, int z){
    city=c;
    street=s;
    number=n;
    zip=z;
}
public Address (Address a)
{
    this.city=city;
    this.street=street;
    this.number=number;
    this.zip=zip;
}
public Address (String c, String s, int n)
{
    zip=0;
    city=c;
    street=s;
    number=n;
}


public String toString(){ 
if (zip==0)
    return "Address: " + street + "st., " + number + ", " + city ;
return "Address: " + street + "st., " + number + ", " + city  + ", " + zip;

}
```

I've added a method that compares values within the object:

```
public boolean sameAddress(Person p){
Person b=new Person (p.getName(), p.getPAddress());
if (p.getName()==name) 
  return true; 
return false;
```

It's supposed to check if the Person's address is the name for both objects.

```
public static void main (String[]args){
Address Home=new Address("New York","5th Avenue", 112, 111);
Person a=new Person("Carl",Home); 
Person b=new Person ("Carl",a.getPAddress()); 
System.out.println(b.sameAddress(a));
```

they have the same address I get a FALSE answer What's wrong here?

Comment: Show us the toString method of Address class. In fact, add the Address class code.

Comment: Where is your `Address` class? (edit: ManishMulani beat me by 30 seconds :P)

Comment: You can change `pAddress = new Address (a);` to `pAddress = a` as well;

Comment: There is something wrong in the copy constructor of the Address class. Could you please show us that?

Comment: I think you just need to change pAddress = new Address (a); to pAddress = a;   Can we see the constructors for Address?

Comment: I will add the Address class now, thanks everyone for the answers.

Comment: Address class added to the original post. thanks everyone again.

Comment: @SaviourSelf - your suggestion works! I just have to ask - doing so won't risk my code with aliasing? the attribute is private, so that's what I'm afraid of.

Comment: @SwapnilS - your suggestion works! I just have to ask - doing so won't risk my code with aliasing? the attribute is private, so that's what I'm afraid of.

Comment: You're setting that private attribute inside a constructor, which is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ahh.... I see your problem.

In your Address constructor where you send it an Address:

```
public Address (Address a)
{
    this.city=city;
    this.street=street;
    this.number=number;
    this.zip=zip;
}
```

You need to change this to:

```
public Address (Address a)
{
    this.city=a.getCity();
    this.street=a.getStreet();
    this.number=a.getNumber();
    this.zip=a.getZip();
}
```

And all of the corresponding setters/getters.

Comment: Thank you, it does work like a charm. The quick answer is much appriciated!

Comment: Hello, It's me again with another question.

Comment: I've added a method that compares values within the object:
[CODE]
 public boolean sameAddress(Person p){
  Person b=new Person (p.getName(), p.getPAddress());
  if (p.getName()==name)
   return true;
  return false;
[/CODE]

It's supposed to check if the Person's address is the name for both objects.

public static void main (String[]args){
  Address Home=new Address("New York","5th Avenue", 112, 111);
  Person a=new Person("Carl",Home);
  Person b=new Person ("Carl",a.getPAddress());
  System.out.println(b.sameAddress(a));

they have the same address I get a FALSE answer

What's wrong here?

Comment: @ Saviour Self - I have another problem which I added in the last comment - I'd be glad if you can help, thanks!

Comment: I've added another question to the first post, the last two codes. glad if you can help! :)  @SwapnilS

Comment: Code in comments is unreadable. If you have another question, then ask another question.